# How to find closed formula for the sum of the first n odd perfect squares?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I do know formula for finding sum of squares of n odd numbers but I am not sure how to find closed formula.

Note: From closed formula I mean a reduced fraction in factored form, with no ellipses (“. . .”) in it.

Comment: You you mean sum of squares of odd numbers, or sums of odd numbers, of which you have $n^2$ of them?

Comment: Please try to place your actual question in both the body and the title...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have the formulas
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\[4pt]
&\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Then

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2 &= \sum_{k=1}^n 4k^2- 4k + 1\\[4pt]
&= 4\sum_{k=1}^n k^2
-4\sum_{k=1}^n k
+\sum_{k=1}^n 1
\\[4pt]
&=
4\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)
-4\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)
+n\\[4pt]
&=\frac{n(2n-1)(2n+1)}{3}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Which formula are you talking about?

Comment: Do you know the formulas

$$1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots +\,n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

$$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots +\,n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

??

Comment: Yes I do know the formulas. Sorry I got confused.